# Update table in Oracle SQL based on individual member id

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having following table

```
Emp_ID   Emp_Name    Insert_Time
001      AAA         12:00
002      BBB         12:00
002      BBB         12:00
003      CCC         12:00
004      DDD         12:00
004      DDD         12:00
```

Now I want to  increment Insert_Time for duplicate records in table itself and display all records.

```
Emp_ID   Emp_Name    Insert_Time
001      AAA         12:00
002      BBB         12:01
002      BBB         12:02
003      CCC         12:00
004      DDD         12:01
004      DDD         12:02
```

How to do this..?

Comment: Don' t tag the DBMS that you are not using.

Comment: Which DBMS? Also, what is the type of Insert_time?

Comment: I'm working in Oracle-SQL developer. Insert_Time is Date type.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table111
    ([Emp_ID] int, [Emp_Name] varchar(3), [Insert_Time] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO #Table111
    ([Emp_ID], [Emp_Name], [Insert_Time])
VALUES
    (001, 'AAA', '12:00'),
    (002, 'BBB', '12:00'),
    (002, 'BBB', '12:00'),
    (003, 'CCC', '12:00'),
    (004, 'DDD', '12:00'),
    (004, 'DDD', '12:00')
;
select * from #Table111

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [EMP_NAME],[EMP_ID] ORDER BY [EMP_ID]) AS RN FROM #TABLE111
)
UPDATE CTE
SET [INSERT_TIME]=   STUFF([INSERT_TIME],4,5,RN)
```

output

```
EMP_ID  EMP_NAME    INSERT_TIME
1          AAA        12:1
2          BBB        12:1
2          BBB        12:2
3          CCC        12:1
4          DDD        12:1
4          DDD        12:2
```

Comment: Whether this will update #Table111 permanently. Coz in last select query, it retireve data from CTE..?
My actual table consists of 20 columns with 100s of records. Do I've to replace all column names instead of [EMP_NAME],[EMP_ID]..?

Answer (score 0):

You may [use](http://rextester.com/RLKV35517) `count` and `row_number` functions together to get the desired result :

```
with tab(Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Insert_Time) as
(
 select '001','AAA','12:00' from dual union all
 select '002','BBB','12:00' from dual union all
 select '002','BBB','12:00' from dual union all
 select '003','CCC','12:00' from dual union all
 select '004','DDD','12:00' from dual union all
 select '004','DDD','12:00' from dual    
)

select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, 
       to_char(to_date(Insert_Time,'hh24:mi') +rn/24/60,'hh24:mi') as Insert_Time
  from
(
  select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Insert_Time,
         count(1) over (partition by Emp_ID order by Emp_ID) cnt,
         row_number() over (partition by Emp_ID order by Emp_ID) rn  
    from tab t 
)
where cnt > 1;

EMP_ID  EMP_NAME    INSERT_TIME
 002      BBB         12:01
 002      BBB         12:02
 004      DDD         12:01
 004      DDD         12:02
```

To update the records as you commented, use :

```
update tab t
   set t.insert_time= (
              select to_char(to_date(Insert_Time,'hh24:mi') +rn/24/60,'hh24:mi') as Insert_Time
                from
              (
                select Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Insert_Time,
                       count(1) over (partition by Emp_ID order by Emp_ID) cnt,
                       row_number() over (partition by Emp_ID order by Emp_ID) rn  
                  from tab t 
              ) q
              where cnt > 1
                and t.Emp_ID = q.Emp_ID
                and t.Emp_Name = q.Emp_Name
                and t.rowid = q.rowid
         );
```

to get :

```
   select * from tab;

   EMP_ID   EMP_NAME    INSERT_TIME
     001      AAA    
     002      BBB          12:01
     002      BBB          12:02
     003      CCC   
     004      DDD          12:01
     004      DDD          12:02
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table like the following:

```
create table yourTable(Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Insert_Time) as (
    select '001', 'AAA', to_date('01/01/0001 12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select '002', 'BBB', to_date('01/01/0001 12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select '002', 'BBB', to_date('01/01/0001 12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select '003', 'CCC', to_date('01/01/0001 12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select '004', 'DDD', to_date('01/01/0001 12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select '004', 'DDD', to_date('01/01/0001 12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
)
```

You can use:

```
select Emp_ID, Emp_Name,
       Insert_Time +
       row_number() over (partition by Emp_ID, Emp_Name order by 1) -- the row number
        * ( count(*) over (partition by Emp_ID, Emp_Name ) -1 )     -- to decide whether to add a minute or not
             / 24 / 60                                              -- to get minutes
          as Insert_Time
from yourTable
```

The result:

```
001 AAA 01/01/0001 12:00:00
002 BBB 01/01/0001 12:01:00
002 BBB 01/01/0001 12:02:00
003 CCC 01/01/0001 12:00:00
004 DDD 01/01/0001 12:01:00
004 DDD 01/01/0001 12:02:00
```

To update the table, you can use a `MERGE`:

```
merge into yourTable T
using (
        select rowid, Emp_ID, Emp_Name,
               Insert_Time +
               row_number() over (partition by Emp_ID, Emp_Name order by 1) -- the row number
                * ( count(*) over (partition by Emp_ID, Emp_Name ) -1 )     -- to decide wheter to add a minute or not
                     / 24 / 60 as Insert_Time
        from yourTable          
      ) X 
on (t.rowid = x.rowid)
when matched then
    update set t.Insert_Time = x.Insert_Time
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to UPDATE the value in table itself. Not just SELECT query for display purpose.